# C++ template argument failed, is not derived from error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in from a file but I'm getting this error.

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:1068:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:35:38: note:   ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’

```
   while(getline(input_file, line_)){
                                  ^
```

I'm relatively new to C++ so I'm not sure what the error actually means. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks. Heres my code.

```
#include "prog.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool prog::readFile() {

ofstream input_file("myText.txt");
string line_; // string which text file contents will be stored in

if(input_file.is_open()){ // validation to see if the file is open
  while(getline(input_file, line_)){
      cout<<line_<< '\n'; //prints the contents of the file into the console
  }
  input_file.close();
}
else {
  cout<<"File is not open"<< '\n';
}
}
```

Comment: One thing, you're using `using namespace std;`, however you still prefix every identifier in that namespace with `std::`. You should settle for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::ofstream` (**out** file stream) is for writing to a file.  You cannot read from a `std::ofstream`.  Use `std::ifstream` (**in** file stream) to read a file, or `std::fstream` if you need to use the same stream to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

`ofstream` is for output, you want `ifstream`.